# Finding the rows with same values having same data in sql using java?

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, greatest-n-per-group, minimum

From the table as I want to get the rows contains minimum value of works as here is 3 so that I can get the rows of id 2 and 5 as both the rows has same minimum value.

```
ID   |   emailID                |   works
------------------------------------------
1    |   tree123@gmail.com      |   5
2    |   tree23@gmail.com       |   3
3    |   hello123@gmail.com     |   5
4    |   thistree123@gmail.com  |   4
5    |   somtng@gmail.com       |   3
```

Comment: in your query statement, add a `WHERE` condition for when works = 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"I want to get the rows that contain the minimum value of works" - You can get that by doing the following:

```
SELECT emailId 
FROM yourTable
WHERE works = (SELECT MIN(works) 
               FROM yourTable)
```

Here is a demonstration of this query in action: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/85fb6/7)

If this is not what you are looking for, please elaborate on your question.